# Use material angular color in component

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, theming

I a have a angular application with material angular. I've build my own theme on [materialtheme.arcsine.dev](https://materialtheme.arcsine.dev/).
This theme is included inside my `angular.json`

```
"styles": [
    "src/theme.scss",
    "src/styles.scss"
],
```

I'm trying to use the colors from my theme inside my custom components.

For example, i have a simple footer

**footer.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.scss']
})
export class FooterComponent { }
```

**footer.component.html**: for now i juste have a simple text

```html
My simple footer
```

And inside my scss file i'm trying to use the theme variables. Originaly i have this file:

```css
:host {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

I added some lines following [material angular guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components)

```css
@use 'sass:map';
@use '~@angular/material' as mat;

$color-config:    mat.get-color-config($theme);
$primary-palette: map.get($color-config, 'primary');
$accent-palette:  map.get($color-config, 'accent');
$warn-palette:    map.get($color-config, 'warn');
$is-dark-theme:   map.get($color-config, 'is-dark');

:host {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    background: mat.get-color-from-palette($primary-palette, '500');
}
```

But when i'm doing this i the following error:

```
SassError: Undefined variable.
  ╷
4 │ $color-config:    mat.get-color-config($theme);
  │                                        ^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\app\Components\FooterComponent\footer.component.scss 4:40  root stylesheet
```

But if i go inside my theme.scss that was generated there is the `$theme`

```css
$theme: (
  primary: $theme-primary,
  accent: $theme-accent,
  warn: $theme-warn,
  is-dark: false,
  foreground: $mat-light-theme-foreground,
  background: $mat-light-theme-background,
);
$altTheme: (
  primary: $theme-primary,
  accent: $theme-accent,
  warn: $theme-warn,
  is-dark: true,
  foreground: $mat-dark-theme-foreground,
  background: $mat-dark-theme-background,
);

// Theme Init
@include mat.all-component-themes($theme);

.theme-alternate {
  @include mat.all-component-themes($altTheme);
}
```

**What can i do to use the theme variables inside my components ?**

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define $theme

```
$theme: mat.define-light-theme((
 color: (
   primary: $my-primary,
   accent: $my-accent,
   warn: $my-warn,
 )
));
```

docs: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#themes

Comment: Inside my theme.scss i already have a $theme and a $altTheme (light and dark theme), how can i import the right one inside my scss component ? I edited my post to show theses variables

Comment: You could use it @ forward from sass check it out @ forward and @ use

Comment: I looked into it, but i don't really understand how to do it. I have tow variables $theme and $altTheme, i didn't find a way to access it, and also access the right one (dark or light theme). Could you provide me more explanation, or do you know a good guide ?